# How do I create an item-by-item unrolling list with jQuery? (example provided)

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, toggle

I am trying to recreate the menu navigation on this website.

http://www.irb-paris.eu/

(when you click on 'Projects' for example, it spawns a line of words that appear one by one).

On my website (http://shinjipons.com/test/index.html), I am trying to achieve the same effect. I tried using **slideToggle()** with jQuery and **toggle()** in jQueryUI with a slide direction to right but that toggle the entire unordered list as a block.

Can anyone shed light on this matter? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a similar solution (forked from @Imperative), but in the context of rolling out from menu links:

http://jsfiddle.net/kE3XW/11/

```
$(function() {

    $('#menu li').children('a').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').children('li').each(function(index) {
            var menuItem = $(this);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                menuItem.fadeIn();
            }, 100 * index);
        });
    });

});
```

And make sure to hide the submenu items using CSS:

```
ul ul li { display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfect. I made some slight adjustments to your answer because I wanted a toggle effect and the <ul> inside the first <ul> made a small padding when the <li> were displayed on more than one line. http://jsfiddle.net/ponsshin/kE3XW/43/

Answer (score 0):

It's quick and dirty, but roughly does what you desire: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekE65/)

```
$(function() {
    var $li = $('#list > li').hide();

    fadeIn(0);

    function fadeIn(i) {
        if (i==$li.length) {
            return false;
        }
        $($li[i]).show();
        var to=window.setTimeout(function() {
            fadeIn(i+1);
        },500);
    }
});
```